# How to filter pivot table between two values?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I am trying to automatically change the filtered range in a multiple pivot tables to a desired four week range at the same time instead of having to manually filter them all.

The Weeks are defined by week numbers 1-52 and not as dates. I have been unable to get any version of code to work on an individual pivot table and have not attempted to write the VBA to affect multiple tables at once.

**Example of pivot table and 4 week range set up**
[image: Example of pivot table and 4 week range set up]

Here is the last attempt. It resulted in

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

highlighting the last line of code.

```vb
Sub Updateweekrange1()
    If Range("T2").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You Must First Enter a Beginning Week#.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Range("V2").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You Must First Enter a Ending Week#.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Test2").PivotFields("Week")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsBetween, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Test2").PivotFields("Week"), Value1:=Range("T2").Value, Value2:=Range("V2").Value
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below and it worked for me.

I solved this by recording a macro (via the initially hidden developer tab), whilst I set a between filter on the Week column and then examined the generated code.

Setting wsPivot to ActiveSheet or perhaps Sheets("Sheet1") for example can allow a bit more flexibility in our coding. I'm autistic; so I can sometimes appear to be schooling others, when I'm only trying to help.

```vb
    Option Explicit
        
    Private Sub Updateweekrange1()
    
    Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
    
    Set wsPivot = ActiveSheet
    
    If wsPivot.Range("T2").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You Must First Enter a Beginning Week#.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
     If wsPivot.Range("V2").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You Must First Enter a Ending Week#.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    With wsPivot.PivotTables("Test2").PivotFields("Week")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFilters.Add2 _
            Type:=xlValueIsBetween, DataField:=wsPivot.PivotTables("Test2"). _
            PivotFields("Sum of Cost"), Value1:=wsPivot.Range("T2").Value, Value2:=wsPivot.Range("V2").Value
    End With
        
    End Sub
```